# How to use javascript to read a url

Tags: javascript

javascript newb here trying to learn. I have been asked at work by the guy who pushes the pages into the different environments this question 
"if theres a way of reading the URL domain and putting it in a variable?
What I am trying to accomplish is not having to change this approot value on our login pages every time I push from QA to uat or live  "
I have been looking online for an answer and so far I have come up empty, can anyone here please help me?

Answer (score 4):

Client side? You can read it from [the `location` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) (which will stringify to give you the full URI of the page).

As a rule of thumb, however, it is better to use either relative URIs or to have a deployment script smart enough to know what environment it is deploying to and use the right configuration for each.